# Sticky position not 'pushing' other sticky elements

Tags: html, css, sticky

I feel like there is an obvious answer here but I cannot work out why – in this mock-up example below – `#one` is not 'pushed' up by `#three`?

Looking at the last [example given by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) it appears that the sticky elements push one-another out of the window whereas here `#one` & `#three` seem to just slide over each other. I feel like it is something to do with the heights(?) but any help with explaining this would be appreciated!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font: bold 20vw Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

#start {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #fff;
}

#one {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/900/1200/?random');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#two {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/800/1200/?random');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#three {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/700/1200/?random');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="start">
  <h1>start</h1>
</div>

<div id="one" class="sticky img">
  <h1>one</h1>
</div>

<div id="two" class="img">
  <h1>two</h1>
</div>

<div id="three" class="sticky img">
  <h1>three</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use that `position: sticky;` inside any wrapper. Here I have updated your dom structure a little bit.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font: bold 20vw Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

#start {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #fff;
}

#one {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00f;
}

#two {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #fff;
}

#three {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #f00;
```

```html
<div id="start">
  <h1>start</h1>
</div>

<div id="one">
  <div class="sticky">
    <h1>one</h1>
  </div>  
</div>

<div id="two">
  <h1>two</h1>
</div>

<div id="three">
  <div class="sticky">
    <h1>Three</h1>
  </div>  
</div>
```

You can also check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs5wbk8h/2/)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks so much for this – would this wrapper also work outside of the divs themselves? It's not actually the text inside the div I am trying to stick to the top but the whole div – so, for example, `#two` overlaps `#one` (which is 50% width) in the initial example and I would like for this to still be possible?

Comment: I guess outsider wrapper will not work, You must have to add a wrapper for each **sticky div**. Or, you can directly add your sticky class to heading like this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ry8gce4/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm being clear – I've updated the div's to have background images to make it more obvious what I mean. I don't want the text within the div to stick at all, I want the `#one` div itself to stick to the top while `#two` passes over it, after which `#three` knocks `#one` out of view?

Answer (score 2):

Div `#three` quite simply needed to be positioned `absolute`!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font: bold 20vw Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

#start {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #fff;
}

#one {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/900/1200/?random');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#two {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/800/1200/?random');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#three {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/700/1200/?random');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="start">
  <h1>start</h1>
</div>

<div id="one" class="sticky img">
  <h1>one</h1>
</div>

<div id="two" class="img">
  <h1>two</h1>
</div>

<div id="three" class="img">
  <h1>three</h1>
</div>
```